# javascript-doesn't wait for the data to return-value is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

The function "classTableData" is called on button click and my allData is undefined.It processes the next line of code without waiting for the results and hence my "allData" is undefined.Can someone help on this?

```
function classTableData(){
     loadStudentPDFData().then(function (results) {
                  studentPDFData = results.pdfData;
                });
        var allData = studentPDFData;
        $log.log("AllData"+allData.length);

    }

function loadStudentPDFData() {
  var deferred = q.defer();
   var core5PDFData=angular.copy(core5InstructionPlanner);
       core5PDFData.loadPDFSection('all', function() {
     deferred.resolve({pdfData:core5PDFData.dataSource('all').data()});
      });
    return deferred.promise;
  }
```

Comment: Put the log in the callback. Promises don't make your code synchronous, you still have to wait for the result.

Answer (score 0):

`loadStudentPDFData` return a promise.

The resolved promise returns the object `{pdfData:core5PDFData.dataSource('all').data()}`.

While you have put `studentPDFData = results.pdfData;` inside the resolve callback, you have another two lines outside it.

```
    var allData = studentPDFData;
    $log.log("AllData"+allData.length);
```

This results in studentPDFData being undefined when it is assigned to `allData` resulting in the logging of `null`.
If you push these two lines inside the callback, it should work.

i.e.

```
 loadStudentPDFData().then(function (results) {
      studentPDFData = results.pdfData;
      var allData = studentPDFData;//you don't need this variable
      $log.log("AllData"+allData.length);
 });
```

Javascript is inherently asynchronous and Promises are an integral part of it. A promise is used to complete actions based upon results which might come to the code later (ex. database calls, or http requests etc.).

You can read more about promises [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) and about the q library [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/q).

Comment: but i need allData to be processed outside this function too,how to achieve that?

Comment: Why do you need it "outside" this function exactly? the function is a mere wrapper over the promise object. It simply shows that the response is received from the loadStudentPDFData promise. Can you show in an example where you need this variable outside?

Comment: i should return the processed allData from the classTableData function.    var classTableDataForPDF = classTableData(); classTableDataForPDF gives undefined value.

Comment: In that case, even the current function needs to return a promise which needs to be consumed later in a similar fashion. JavaScript is different :)

Answer (score 0):

Perform the task within `.then()`

```
loadStudentPDFData()
.then(function (results) {
  $log.log("AllData" + results.pdfData.length);
  return results.pdfData
});
```

if a `.then()` is chained to `classTableData` `return` `loadStudentPDFData()` from `classTableData()` function

```
function classTableData() {
  return loadStudentPDFData()
         .then(function (results) {
           $log.log("AllData" + results.pdfData.length);
           return results.pdfData
         });
}
```